# Error message regarding array index

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why am I getting the error message: "Line[i] is undefined" in the following code? It might be something trivial, but I just can't fix it.

It works, for example, if I use `Line[0]` or `Line[1]`, etc.

But I need to iterate through the loop.

```
var Line = [{ Func: "Function"}];
for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    Line[i].Func = "Function" + I;
}
```

Comment: your `Line` is one element array `[0 => {Func:...}]` so `Line[1]` is undefined, therefore `Line[1].Func` is undefined

Comment: Well, you loop through 16 items of a single-item array... Are you trying to append new items?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to iterate to `i <= 15` and getting error when JavaScript evaluate `Line[1]` because it is `undefined`

Instead you can iterate til the length of `Line` array:

```js
var Line = [{ Func: "Function"}];
for (var i = 0, len = Line.length; i < len; i++) {
  Line[i].Func = "Function" + i;
}

console.log(Line);
```

Or iterate using [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
var Line = [{ Func: "Function"}];
Line.forEach((el, index) => el.Func = "Function" + index);

console.log(Line);
```

Or do your way but first check the element `Line[i]` exist:

```js
var Line = [{ Func: "Function"}];
for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
  Line[i] && (Line[i].Func = "Function" + i);
  console.log(i);
}

console.log(Line);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have only one element in the array.

```
var Line = [{ Func: "Function"}];
for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++) { console.log(i); Line[i].Func = "Function" + i;}
```

will print 0 and 1 and then it will throw an error

Answer (score 0):

Your Line array has only 1 object inside it and you are looping from 0 to 15, so after Line[0] it cannot find Line[1] or Line[2].
You probably want to add an object 15 times to Line.
Try something like this within your for loop:

```
Line.push({Func:"Function" + i});
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Answer (score 0):

You are looping from 0 through to 15, and using the loop variable as an index into an array that only has 1 element (index=0)

Looks like you're trying to add new elements

```
var Line = [{ Func: "Function"}];
for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    Line[i] = {Func:"Function" + i}; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a one-length array and you're iterating up to 15. So, you can either check the array limit, or provide a default value up to 15.

This is how you can provide a default value up to 15:

```
var Line = [{ Func: "Function"}];
for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
  if (Line[i] === undefined) {
      Line[i] = { Func: "Function"}
  }
  Line[i].Func = "Function" + i;
}
```

On the other hand, this is how you can go through the actual list, regardless of the element number:

```
var Line = [{ Func: "Function"}];
for (var i = 0; i <= Line.length; i++) {
  Line[i].Func = "Function" + i;
}
```